# Is there a command-line alternative to SOAP-UI for linux, for sending SOAP to HTTPS Service?

Tags: java, linux, web-services, soap, https

I wish to run **SOAP-UI** on a linux (solaris) machine with very limited functionality, where we don't even have a UI, and so I cannot install any software on it or open X11 forwarding.

I can however run java applications, and could settle for any alternative to SOAP-UI.

The objective is to be able to send a SOAP message as-is to an HTTPS URL.

I have tried sending the request from my own java application, however I need something more trustworthy as the '**404 Not Found**' response i'm getting doesn't make sense, while a GET to the same URL is sending me back the WSDL file of the Web Service.

Comment: Just found a solution for this (below), hope it works:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a guide for this [here](http://blog.kasunbg.org/2013/04/run-soapui-command-line-terminal-linux.html), which does load tests.

For normal functional tests, the official documentation is [here](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html).

A sample command for functional tests goes like:

> sh /opt/app/home/SOAP-UI/SoapUI-5.0.0/bin/testrunner.sh -a -s"Test_Suite2" -r -f/opt/app/home/SOAP-UI/test-project/reports/ /opt/app/home/SOAP-UI/test-project/test-soapui-project.xml